# Tapered Line in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to draw some animated blades of grass and I want to generate a tapered curve that is thicker at the bottom and thinner at the top.  The only way I could imagine out to do this was to draw curves each with a lesser length and larger line width.

I was curious if anyone had a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following function. It draws an open outline of a grass. You may modify it to meet your need. Coded for Raphael.

```
/**
 * drawAGrass draws an open base grass.
 * @param   paper   Raphael paper instance
 * @param   baseX   X position of the grass base center
 * @param   baseY   Y position of the grass base center
 * @param   baseW   Width of the grass base
 * @param   length  Length of the grass
 * @param   tilt    Angle of shift of the grass tip; Safe range: [-45, 45]
 */
function drawAGrass (paper, baseX, baseY, baseW, length, tilt) {
    var x1 = baseX + baseW * 0.5,
        x2 = baseX - baseW * 0.5,
        ang = (180 - tilt) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = Math.round(baseX + length * Math.sin(ang)),
        y = Math.round(baseY + length * Math.cos(ang));

    paper.path(['M', baseX, baseY, 'Q', baseX, y, x, y]);
    paper.path(['M', x1, baseY, 'Q', x1, y, x, y]);
    paper.path(['M', x2, baseY, 'Q', x2, y, x, y]);
}
```

Use it like the following.

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 350);
drawAGrass(paper, 250, 330, 15, 150, 25);
```